# How do you invoke a method with any signature dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#

I had a class with some common error handling code, and I wanted to pass in the method and arguments to call, but I couldn't quite come up with the syntax.  What I want to do is roughly this:

```
private void InvokeHelper(Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
  bool retry = false;

  do
  {
    try
    {
      method.DynamicInvoke(args);
      retry = false;
    }
    catch (MyException ex)
    {
      retry = HandleException(ex);
    }
  } while (retry);
}
```

and then be able to do things like:

```
InvokeHelper(foo.MethodA, a, b, c);
InvokeHelper(foo.MethodB, x, y );
```

This gets a compiler error converting foo.MethodA and foo.MethodB into System.Delegate.  I came up with the workaround below (and I actually like it better because then I get type checking on my arguments to my methods), but I'm curious if there's a way to do what I was originally trying to do?  I know I could use `foo.GetType().GetMethod("MethodA")` and invoke that, but I was trying to avoid reflection.  I mainly just want to understand how methods are dynamically invoked in .net.

Workaround:

```
private delegate void EmptyDelegate();

private void InvokeHelper(EmptyDelegate method)
{
  bool retry = false;

  do
  {
    try
    {
      method.Invoke();
      retry = false;
    }
    catch (MyException ex)
    {
      retry = HandleException(ex);
    }
  } while (retry);
}
```

then call:

```
InvokeHelper(delegate() { foo.MethodA(a, b, c); });
InvokeHelper(delegate() { foo.MethodB(x, y); });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your signature is

```
private void InvokeHelper(Delegate method, params object[] args)
```

Yet you're making the mistake that you have to group your args into an array to call this method:

```
InvokeHelper(foo.MethodA, new object[] { a, b, c});
```

The `parms` keyword tells the compiler to do this for you; you can call this method thusly:

```
InvokeHelper(foo.MethodA, a, b, c);
```

Second, if you're targeting 3.0 or greater, don't use Delegate, use Action:

```
private void InvokeHelper(Action method)
```

and call it this way:

```
InvokeHelper(()=> MyMethodToInvoke(a, b, c));
```

which is just an overall better way of doing this.

---

As to why you're getting the compiler issue, its because System.Delegates hate us.  Its a simple fact.  That, and because there is no implicit cast from method group to Delegate.

Comment: "there is no implicit cast from method group to Delegate".  Bingo.  A method has an explicitly declared parameter list.  Usually the compiler helps you figure out which overload in the methodgroup to use by checking the parameters' types.  Here the compiler cannot do that.

Comment: I changed it to not explicitly construct an object array.  Don't know why I thought I needed to do that -- brain fart I guess.

Comment: It took me a LONG time to break myself of that habit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a re-write, following Will's advice to use Action:

```
    private void InvokeHelper(Action method)
    {
        bool retry = false;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                method();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (MyException ex)
            {
                retry = HandleException(ex);
            }
        } while (retry);
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        FooClass foo = new FooClass();
        InvokeHelper( () => foo.MethodA(1, "b", 3) );
        InvokeHelper( () => foo.MethodB(2, "y"));
    }
```